# Shoelace Algorithm For Parallelogram

Tags: geometry, area

Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices at (−5,−4), (−13,−9), (3,7), and (−5,2).

---

I tried using shoelace algorithm and got 20 but my homework checker says it is wrong.

$[(-5 \times -9)-(-13 \times-4)]+[(-13 \times 7)+(3 \times-9)]+[(3 \times 2)+ (-5 \times 7)]+[(-5 \times4)+(-5 \times 2)]=area$

$ -7 + -64 + 41 + -10 = area$

$area = \frac{\mid-40 \mid}{2} $

$area= 20$

Comment: Kindly provide your calculations in the post so that we may assist you.

Comment: I have added the calculations

Comment: Do you know about cross product of vectors ?

Comment: Hint: are your points in the correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know that your quadrilateral is a parallelogram, it is much faster to just compute the vector product between $A-B$ and $A-C$, where $A=(3;7), B=(-5;2), C=(-5;-4)$. This boils down to computing the absolute value of
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}8 & 5 \\ 8 & 11\end{pmatrix} $$
that is $8\cdot 6 = \color{red}{48}$. Notice that in the shoelace formula you should have $8$ terms, $4$ terms took with the positive sign and four terms took with the negative sign.